Create a directory to store the .json
I try to create a directory to store the .json, but I get the following error:

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/root/.kaggle’: File exists

I was hoping to create a directory to store the .json, like this:
!mkdir ~/.kaggle
!cp /content/kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/
!chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json


As the error message mentions, it cannot create /root/.kaggle because it already exists.
You would want to make the directory only when it does not already exists. Hence you can use the -p flag along with mkdir, like this:
!mkdir -p ~/.kaggle

You can also reference to How to mkdir only if a directory does not already exist?.
